# How to deploy a Spring boot application to weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 without deploy a WAR file?

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

I have no right to access the weblogic.Deployer stuff nor the web admin GUI (if that exists in Linux server version)

I can only upload file via FTP to a deployment folder (there are jsp/META-INF/WEB-INF sub folders) where the admin setup to us.
And the admin also provide us a script to restart the app server. (OS is linux)

I wonder if this is possible to unzip the WAR file and upload files to server and restart the app server to get it started?

I actually tried and unable to see any spring related stdout and logs. The app server only show not found in web browser. just like the application does not exist at all.

I can deploy the WAR file in weblogic (windows edition). the app files should be ok.

Comment: Where in Weblogic is this jsp/META-INF/WEB-INF directory located?

Comment: I think the location is not "in" weblogic.
just a place mapped externally for the admin to easily manage those multiple hosts.
its like "/export/asu/deploy/{host_name}/"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to deploy the exploded Spring Boot WAR to the folder.

But it's import that you change the context path in application.properties to match the context path the app will run under in Weblogic:

```
server.servlet.context-path=<the context path>
```

Comment: thx for reply.
tried your code but no luck.

there is no stdout/log about the Spring app. its like the Spring app didn't get initialized at all.

one more info. I have weblogic.xml but no web.xml. wonder this is the problem....

Comment: You don't need web.xml Can you show how your directory structure looks like?

Comment: just figured out i can only format my message in answer... folder structure is in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
META-INF\maven\com.example\demo\pom.properties
                               \pom.xml
        \MANIFEST.MF 
org\springframework\boot\loader\some folders and classes 
WEB-INF\classes\com\example\demo\RootController.class 
                                \ServletInitializer.class 
                                \DemoApplication.class 
               \application.properties 
        \lib\and some jars 
        \lib-provided\and some jars 
        \dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml
        \weblogic.xml
```

Comment: How does the pom.xml file affect the application start up?
I saw so many solutions talking about editing the pom.xml. 
As far as i know, the file is used for packaging file. 
I wonder how the properties in the file affects the application boot up?
e.g. the start-class properties

Answer (score 0):

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:context-root>/</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <!-- added these after some google -->
            <wls:package-name>javax.validation</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.el</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence</wls:package-name>
            <!-- added above after some google -->

            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```